# MS Graph, Calendar deltalink shows appointment as deleted when it is not

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm using MS Graph to sync appointments between an Office 365 calendar and our app. I've set up a subscription for the resource and receive notifications for the created, updated and deleted events. I then use the deltalink I have stored for the subscription to get the changes. Most of the time this works very well.

However, sometimes after receiving a notification and using the deltalink, the results will show the appointment as deleted when it really isn't. IE, in the json it will only show "@removed":{"reason":"deleted"} and the id of the appointment. However when I then get the appointment with this id through the /calendar/events/{itemId} endpoint, I do get all the information of this appointment, meaning it's not deleted or it wouldn't even exist.

Once a subscription is in this state it doesn't appear to recover as the next deltalink will have the same problem. Deleting the subscription and getting a new deltalink will fix it.

I have no idea what causes this as the deltalink does get the right appointment, it just gives the wrong information for the appointment. I know that when I use an out of date deltalink I get a SyncStateNotFound error, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer or did you go another way?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. In the end I had to add an extra check whether or not the appointment was actually deleted or not.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done too. The beta channel of Graph should have a solution for this, see this GH issue: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6599.